# How can I customize the ending node style while saving an XmlDocument?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

Simply put, after calling `XmlDocument.Save` method, I want the resulting xml look like this:

```
<somenode />
```

instead of this:

```
<somenode></somenode>
```

Can I achieve this?

I don't think how I constructed the XmlDocument matters. I just have such an instance, make some changes and save it. I want to know if it's possible to control the formatting for empty node.

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Give more context like e.g. the xml processor used or the programming language etc.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp, the OP mentioned in the title XmlDocument which I suppose refers to the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class in .NET.

Comment: I'm sorry for causing any confusion. Yes, I'm playing with C#. The situation is that I know that there're going to be some empty node, with no child elements. So now I want to know if it's possible to control this behavior.

Comment: How is this xml being generated? Has it been loaded as a string via an XmlDocument.LoadXml, or from another source via XmlDocument.Load, or is it being dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

It's done automatically for elements that have no child elements, and it's illegal for elements that have child elements... so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.